# Safely update php 5.3.3 to >=5.3.4 on centos 6

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos6, update

Would the following works fine without any issues? I have apc cache installed, the other packages the usual php configuration.

```
 yum update php
```

would that be enough?

it is an active server, so want to make sure and see what should I take into consideration to make this less painful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For people running PHP-based web sites, it's almost always required to track bug fix changes as well as the security fixes that Red Hat might provide. As you know they rarely provide bug fix updates, due to "enterprise" version locking, even for something like PHP where you really need them.

On my production web servers I have used the [remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/) for many years. It provides current versions of PHP, MySQL, Symfony, and many related packages that need such updates on a regular basis. As of this writing, it provides PHP 5.4.33 and MySQL 5.5.40. (PHP 5.5 is available in remi-php55.)

The main difference you will notice is that your PHP bugs start going away... :)

Comment: I added remi repo  using a centos on a VM and it worked.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As madhatter reminded me, a yum update will bring you up to the latest redhat php release, at the time of writing this appears to be: 5.3.3-14.el6_3

In any event your plan of action should be something along the lines of:

1. Schedule a maintenance window
2. Create a test plan
3. Shutdown apache
4. update php `yum update php`
5. start apache
6. Execute test plan

If your test plan fails you can downgrade php, `yum downgrade php` that said I would test this all using a "throw away" vm, that way you can run through all of this without any risk to the production system.

Is there a particular need for 5.3.4 or is this just a security concern?

Note: redhat backport security and bug fixes into their releases.

5.3.3-14 for instance indicates php 5.3.3 with 14 redhat itterations:

i.e.

> - Mon Jun 25 2012 Joe Orton  - 5.3.3-14
> - add security fix for CVE-2010-2950
> - Wed Jun 13 2012 Joe Orton  - 5.3.3-13
> - fix tests for CVE-2012-2143, CVE-2012-0789
> - Tue Jun 12 2012 Joe Orton  - 5.3.3-12
> - add fix for CVE-2012-2336

Comment: Sorry, a rare downvote for an answer here, because that simply won't do what the OP wants.  It'll definitely bring php-5.3.3 up to Red Hat's latest patch state for 5.3.3, but that's not the aim of his or her game.

Comment: @MadHatter ah indeed, that does bring it to: 5.3.3-14.el6_3 edited my answer.

Comment: Downvote recanted!  Have an upvote instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes we need to upgrade to 5.3.4 to fix a php bug that is causing us a lot of trouble. it is fixed in 5.3.4.

Comment: This is the bug I want to fix without turning off zend.enable_gc: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027

Comment: @Oneiroi how can I find wich bugs are solved in the patches?
For example I would like to know if the solved issue  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62715 has been pathced in the 5.3.3 centos version.

Comment: @cirpo changelogs included with the rpms; e.g. once installed `rpm -q package_name --changelog`

Answer (score 2):

CentOS 6 does not have PHP 5.3.4 in the standard repositories, which you can see [here](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/). `yum update php` will not upgrade you to 5.3.4.

Think long and hard about why you want to upgrade. CentOS and it's upstream vendor have not included 5.3.4 yet because it has not been tested.

If you really want to continue, you can check out the list of [Third Party Repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories#line-34). I don't actually see any that have PHP 5.3.4 but I didn't look too hard.

Once you find a repo with the packages you want, gather your current list of PHP packages with `rpm -qa | grep php`. Run `yum update php` and it should show you what it wants to update. It should match everything in your currently installed list but have newer versions. If yum doesn't match your currently installed list, don't update.

Comment: Much better answer, though still wrong about why C6 doesn't have php 5.3.4.  The answer is in Red Hat's patching policy, which says that whatever version of a tool RHEL6 has on ship date, that will be the version of that tool it will have through its whole life.  RH will backport patches, and make sure that that their php5.3.3 stays usable for the life of EL6, but they will **never** upgrade it.  CentOS faithfully mirrors upstream in this, as in nearly all, respects.

Comment: Thanks, I need to either downgrade it to earlier version like 5.2 or upgrade to 5.3.4. there is a bug in the versions between with Garbage Collection.  that redhat policy then it would mean centos6 will continue to have buggy php. I guess I have no choice but to use third party?

Comment: Actually RHEL version locked several months before they even went into beta. Which is frustrating because of the PHP bug that will never get fixed...

Comment: @MadHatter: that makes sense.  Thus the custom `5.3.3-24` minor versioning in their standard packages, where it's still PHP 5.3.3, but with only certain chosen and tested critical fixes matching only some PHP official version 5.3.24 updates.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: close.  Rather, it's the 24th version of php-5.3.3 that RH have released, each with slightly more fixes to the 5.3.3 codebase, most of which fixes are backported from later versions.