# Upgrade to latest current installed version of PHP

Tags: linux, php, centos5

I've just purchased a new VPS and they've, for some unknown reason, installed PHP version 5.3.3. I'm fine with being on version 5.3.X, but I believe the latest version is 5.3.29.

I did some Googling but couldn't find the answer, so wondered how I upgrade the PHP install to the latest 5.3.X version?

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/q/451466/126632

Answer (score 1):

RedHat doesn't keep up with latest changes and only backports security fixes. So you will be stuck at 5.3.3 as long as you are on RHEL/CentOS 6. This is to ensure stability of enterprise systems. Like you said, you don't want 5.6 or something.

Install the [IUS Repo](https://iuscommunity.org/pages/Repos.html) to get newer versions of PHP. They've deprecated 5.3 to their Archive repo, but you can still get it. After installing the repo edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/ius-archive.repo` and set `enabled=1` for [ius-archive]

```
[ius-archive]
name=IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Archive
#baseurl=http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/CentOS/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=http://dmirr.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist/?repo=ius-centos6-archive&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
```

Then remove your current php and install the IUS one.

```
yum remove php
yum install php53u
```

If you need to replace php without uninstalling anything that depends on it you can install the yum plugin "replace". More info in the [IUS docs](https://iuscommunity.org/pages/IUSClientUsageGuide.html#upgrading-stock-rhel-packages-to-ius-packages).

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace php --replace-with php53u
```

IUS has the latest 5.3.29 in their Archive as well as 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6 in their active repos.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
sudo yum update php
```

will update php and it's dependencies to the latest version that hase been released by CentOS.

Comment: Cool, I figured yum might do it... but I don't want it to bump me up to 5.6, or even 5.5, for example. So using yum's update won't upgrade me to the latest version?

Comment: No running yum update on CentOs and RHEL will not upgrade the version of packages, only the patch level should increase. Please refer to Red Hat's [backporting](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) policy which is the basis for the CentOS patch policy as well.

Comment: @HBruijn I was very careful with my language - it will update it to the latest released by CentOS.

Comment: @Iain which, if it's 5.6, will mean I will be bumped up to 5.6? I'm just trying to make sure I don't end up on 5.6 which will probably break many things!

Comment: @Ashley It won't be 5.6 CentOS doesn't work like that, even CentOS 6.5 only has php 5.3.3.

Comment: @Iain Hmm okay, is there any way of telling which version it will be bumped to? I'm kinda guessing it might not do anything as I'm on CentOS 5.

Comment: @Ashley `yum update php` will tell you what it's going to do and request permission prior to doing it. Why is  this a problem anyway you're doing it on a test system aren't you ?